# Charge Renormalization in Peskin (Chapter 7.5)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization

In Chapter 7.5 in Peskin and Schroeder, the authors define the physical charge in eq. (7.76),
$$\text{(physical charge)}=\sqrt{Z_3}\cdot\text{(bare charge)}$$
where $\dfrac{1}{1-\Pi(0)}\equiv Z_3$. Here,
$$\Pi^{\mu\nu}(q)=(q^2g^{\mu\nu}-q^\mu q^\nu)\Pi(q^2)$$
$i\Pi^{\mu\nu}(q)$ being the sum of all 1PI insertions into the photon propagator.

Now, just below eq. (7.76), the authors say that in a scattering process with non-zero $q^2$, we get a quantity,
$$\frac{-ig_{\mu\nu}}{q^2}\left(\frac{e_0^2}{1-\Pi(q^2)}\right){\underset{\mathrm{\mathcal{O}(\alpha)}}{=}}\frac{-ig_{\mu\nu}}{q^2}\left(\frac{e^2}{1-[\Pi_2(q^2)-\Pi_2(0)]}\right)$$
where $\Pi_2(q^2)$ is the $\mathcal{O}(\alpha)$ value of $\Pi(q^2)$.

My specific question is, why do we subtract $\Pi_2(0)$ in the denominator of the RHS of the above expression? Shouldn't we just replace $\Pi(q^2)$ with $\Pi_2(q^2)$?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I think the answer lies *a posteriori* in the discussion leading up to eq. (7.90). They show that the $\mathcal{O}(\alpha)$ shift in the electric charge is given by,
$$\Pi_2(0)\approx-\frac{2\alpha}{3\pi\epsilon}$$
which blows up as $\epsilon\rightarrow0$ ($\epsilon=4-d$, $d$ being the number of spacetime dimensions). The argument is:

> What can be observed is the $q^2$ dependence of the effective electric charge (7.77).

[(7.77) basically refers to the denominator I was talking about in my original question.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, replacing the $e_0$ with $e$; secondly, using the Taylor series and dropping the higher order terms. Below is the specific derivation

$$\frac{e_0^2}{1-\Pi(q^2)}\approx\frac{e_0^2}{1-\Pi_2(q^2)}\approx\frac{e^2}{[1-\Pi_2(q^2)]\cdot[1-\Pi_2(0)]^{-1}}\approx\frac{e^2}{[1-\Pi_2(q^2)]\cdot[1+\Pi_2(0)]}\\\approx\frac{e^2}{1-[\Pi_2(q^2)-\Pi_2(0)]}$$

Comment: Note that we have an [equation editor built into the site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) which helps for readability of your post.